# How to set the div width dynamically

Tags: css, vb.net, html, dynamic, width

I want to set the width of a div using a value from my datasource. Is this possible?

I tried using the code below but the width is not set.

```
<%-- Percentage Complete --%>
<div runat="server" style="width: 100%; background-color: aqua;">
    <div style="width:<%#(Eval("Percentage"))%>;background-color:yellow;">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is to show the progress so far like a progress bar.

Thanks

David

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the <%#(Eval("Percentage"))%> inside double quotes like this "<%#(Eval("Percentage"))%>"

Comment: can you not make the div a panel (or runat server) and set it on the attributes in the itemdatabound, if not then try using single quotes for the style=

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use single quotes for the style attribute then double quotes as delimeters around the vb.net code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see a DIV if its empty even though you have set a width to it. It works if you set both width and height properties to it. 
Also, I see that there is no unit - pixel or percent- specified for width. Your code should look something like

```
 <div style='width:<%#(Eval("Percentage"))%>px;height:28px;background-color:yellow;'>
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please Vote up if you are satisfied with the answer.